# Does DefaultModelBinder use information found in CultureInfo instance when binding to non-DateTime properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

I'm trying to wrap my head around `CultureInfo` class.

Implementations of  `IValueProvider.GetValue`  must return an instance `ValueProviderResult`, where its constructor specifies `CultureInfo` as one of its parameters. I understand that `DefaultModelBinder` needs `CultureInfo` instance when binding values to properties of type `DateTime`, but does default binder also use information in `CultureInfo` when binding values to properties of types other than `DateTime`?

Thank you